# AJAX IRCX Client and Server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, chat

I am currently developing an IRCX AJAX Chat based system and have a few questions regarding  the Server and Client implementation; Any suggestions are welcome:

### Server

Should this be implemented as a Web Service, or a Windows Form application? I have experience in developing Windows Forms based servers, however I am wondering if this would be better implemented as a Web Service and if so, why?

### Client

How are Web Based Clients implemented today and what is the preferred method to implement a Web Based Client?

My solution so far are

- ASP.NET Web Forms with an AJAX Update Panel (This seems the most viable)
- Using jQuery connecting to the web service with a JavaScript timeout

### Polling

How frequently should the server be polled for new messages?  0.5 seconds seems a bit excessive and anything between 2 or 3 seconds seems sluggish.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe using ASP.NET (Sockets and an Update Panel) seems to be the best approach.  Using jQuery in this context now seems a bit invalid because it would not maintain a persistent state with the Chat Server which is required for Real Time Communication.

An alternative way I found would be using a Web Sockets and Backbone.JS to deal with the data returned from the server.

http://blog.fogcreek.com/the-trello-tech-stack/

Answer (score 6):

Have a pool of connections and maintain a sort of proxy between the server and clients that sends the data to the right client based on a session id.  This would mean your chat server is protected against packet attacks and you would not have to deal with web sockets which an attacker could hijack and do what they require with it.

Answer (score 4):

I know the question is old, but there's an even better approach now.

SignalR is designed for things like this (real time web functionality)

> SignalR can be used to add any sort of "real-time" web functionality to your ASP.NET application. While chat is often used as an example, you can do a whole lot more. Any time a user refreshes a web page to see new data, or the page implements Ajax long polling to retrieve new data, is candidate for using SignalR.

Here's a tutorial for a basic chat application [HERE](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr).

For more information, visit the [SignalR website](http://signalr.net/).

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I have already implemented this using C# ASP.NET MVC/AJAX and long polling. I also looked at JABBR which uses SignalR which is a pretty neat client.